# GCD deadlocks when all running tasks are waiting, does not start pending tasks

Tags: objective-c, multithreading

I have a recursive function that schedules new tasks on a concurrent queue. I would like to limit the number of simultaneously scheduled tasks and so I use a semaphore so that each task will wait on it until the older threads end and signal the semaphore.

However I find that the queue gets deadlocked when the maximum number of running threads (64) is reached and they all begin waiting on the semaphore. Then GCD doesn't start new tasks even though it has plenty in its pending queue.

What am I doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification 
{
    dispatch_semaphore_t sem = dispatch_semaphore_create(10);

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sem, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^
               {
                   [self recurWithSemaphore:sem];
               });
}

- (void)recurWithSemaphore:(dispatch_semaphore_t)sem
{
    // do some lengthy work here...

    // at this point we're done all but scheduling new tasks so let new tasks be created
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(sem);

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        // don't schedule new tasks until we have enough semaphore
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(sem, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^
                   {
                       [self recurWithSemaphore:sem];
                   });
    }
}
```

Comment: I already thought about NSOperationQueue but limiting the number of concurrent threads is not the same as limiting the number of *scheduled* tasks. Scheduled tasks consume a lot of memory even when they are not running, so I want to postpone the moment the tasks get scheduled.

Comment: In my code, each thread concurrently tries to spawn as many child tasks as possible, but due to contention with other tasks, it ends up waiting on the semaphore, and so none of the threads never exits. So the number of threads reaches some GCD maximum (about 70) and then it deadlocks. Theoretically, GCD should launch new tasks from the pending queue, when the running tasks are blocked. Am I wrong?

Comment: And yes, I've already tried to use a serial "dispatcher" queue to start new threads in a regulated manner, but having all concurrent threads syncing with the single dispatcher queue is a huge performance bottleneck. So I am trying to sync using the semaphore.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "you're waiting synchronously, but effectively signally asynchronously" and why recursion matters. There is a bunch of threads which wait for each other using a semaphore. It is what semaphore is made for, isn't it?

Comment: "But for most practical applications that isn't really material" - I disagree. My task is not made up, it's a typical pattern when the app can have an unlimited number of concurrent tasks - e.g. walking through an unlimited list or tree of data and processing each node independently of others. The GCD does a good job of limiting the number of threads but unfortunately scheduled tasks consume about 10 - 100 KB each and it quick;y becomes a problem. BTW I switched to dispatch_async_f to use functions instead of blocks and control what is being captured, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: @Rob, where did you get that number 500 bytes?

Comment: Here's what the docs say: "...  although you could create 10,000 operation objects and submit them to an operation queue, doing so would cause your application to allocate a potentially nontrivial amount of memory, which could lead to paging and decreased performance."  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ConcurrencyandApplicationDesign/ConcurrencyandApplicationDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH100-SW6     I found this is exactly the case and trying to postpone scheduling tasks.

Comment: You're right, each scheduled task takes about 500-1000 B. Then if you have say 500k operations in total it's 50-100 MB and it becomes a problem. The memory is recovered after completion but the app's RAM footprint remains high because some memory blocks remain "reserved" by your app and do not return to the system.

Comment: Anyway, the pattern you referenced is not relevant in my case because it’s only good for synchronous resources, like synchronous I/O, but threads are asynchronous, so I need to signal the semaphore in another thread, by definition. If you signal the semaphore immediately after calling dispatch_async, you will not reach the goal – to limit the number of scheduled tasks – because the counter of semaphore will be immediately decremented, while in fact the number of scheduled and running threads remains the same, and therefore the threads will get scheduled endlessly.

Comment: I have just found another bummer: when the app reaches GCD’s limit of threads, for example all threads blocked in slow I/O, then the *main* thread is blocked too and the UI begins beachballing! This is a real show stopper :(

Comment: Yes, I need to recursively create new tasks because I'm walking through a tree structure processing each node, and the number of nodes becomes known only after the lengthy processing of the node.

Comment: But please I'd like to hear the trivial answer as well :)

Comment: Oops where's the second Rob's post gone? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical pattern when using semaphores to control access to a limited resource is

- Create semaphore with non-zero value;
- For every task:

  - When starting, "wait" for semaphore (thereby consuming one of the available signals, or if one not available, wait for one); and
  - When done, "signal" semaphore (making it available for another task).

So, let's say you wanted to start 1,000,000 tasks, only 4 concurrently at any given time, you could do something like:

```
dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(4);

dispatch_queue_t queue = ... // some concurrent queue, either global or your own

dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    for (long index = 0; index < 1000000; index++) {
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
            [self performSomeActionWithIndex:index completion:^{
                dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
            }];
        });
    }
});
```

Clearly, if you're dynamically adding more tasks to perform, you could change this from a `for` loop into a `while` loop, checking some synchronized source, but the idea is the same.

The key observation, though, is that I don't have `performSomeActionWithIndex`, itself, recursively creating tasks itself (because then you get into the deadlock situation of the original question where tasks are stopped because they can't start new tasks).

Now, I don't know if your problem can be refactored into this sort of pattern, but if you can, this might be an option.

---

By the way, for the sake of completeness, I'd point out that the typical solution for controlling the degree of concurrency is to use operation queues rather than dispatch queues, in which case you can specify `maxConcurrentOperationCount`.

As you correctly pointed out, there are memory implications of that. In my tests, each scheduled operation takes up at least 500 bytes (and likely more in real-world scenarios), so if you really have more than, say, 5,000-10,000 tasks to be scheduled, operation queues may quickly become impractical. As you advised, future readers should refer to the [Performance Implications](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ConcurrencyandApplicationDesign/ConcurrencyandApplicationDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH100-SW6) section in *Concurrency Programming Guide: Concurrency and Application Design.*

I know that this is not a viable approach in your case, but I only mention it for the benefit of future readers. I would generally advise the use of operation queues when one needs to control the degree of concurrency. I would only jump to an approach like the one outlined above if you're dealing with so many tasks that one can't reasonably just schedule them on an operation queue.

Comment: Thanks Rob, this works, now please help me understand why recursion is an issue in my code?

Comment: You rapidly get to a point where it deadlocks because tasks are blocked, waiting to schedule subtasks that can't be scheduled until one of the prior tasks finish. If you move the scheduling of subtasks to a dedicated "scheduler" process, like above, it resolves this. But, be careful about how much memory your model requires to keep track of these scheduled tasks (or else you're just dealing with another manifestation of the problem that caused you to reject operation queues).

Comment: In my case this would require the "scheduler" to run in a serial queue and all concurrent subtasks to have to sync with it, which would create a great bottleneck compared to all tasks starting subtasks on their own without limit. I've already tried this...

Comment: BTW I've also tried NSOperationQueue and while it works to control the number of threads, it's also unfortunately a few times less efficient than the "wild" uncontrolled GCD.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rob, I seem to have finally found the perfect solution, that a) limits the number of concurrent and scheduled tasks b) therefore optimizes memory footprint c) does not have a performance penalty d) still is pure GCD. The solution is to have a limited pool of concurrent threads which share the common stack of task data (accessed using a semaphore mutex). At the end of its lengthy job each thread pops another task from the stack if any, and schedules more threads if there are more tasks in the stack and the number of threads is still lower than max.

Comment: The solution does not use a serial dispatcher queue and so the bottleneck is not created, and the semaphore syncing works much faster than I expected!